# MatLab webread not downloading full HTML

Tags: matlab

when I use webread it does not seem do download the full html. 
For example webread('https://www.youtube.com') will download most of the html. But lets I want it to download html like is seen in developer tools of chrome. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It is possible that javascript dynamically adds elements to the DOM. Since `webread` doesn't execute javascript, you won't see these

Answer (score 0):

If it is suitable to use external Java Archives, you could give a try on [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/).

After you have [downloaded](https://jsoup.org/download) the `.jar` file:

```
% Add to the JAva classpath
javaaddpath('full_path_to_jsoup_jar');

% Connect tot the specified URL
jSoup = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect('http://youtube.com');
% Get the DOM
document = jSoupDoc.get();
```

This snippet will return the DOM document of the specified page.

You can also the the proxy -if you have any- before getting the content as:

```
jSoup.proxy('your_proxy', your_proxy_port)
```